# File name and class name different in java

Tags: java, class

I created a file named In.java an entered the following code

```
class In {
   int a;

   public static void main(
      String args[] ) {
      Inheritance h = new Inheritance();
      h.set( 6 );
      System.out.println( h.get() );
   }

   void set(
      int a ) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   int get() {
      System.out.println( a );
      return a;
   }
}
```

When I compiled it showed me an error regarding Inheritance. Then I renamed In as I Inheritance

```
class Inheritance {
   int a;

   public static void main(
      String args[] ) {
      Inheritance h = new Inheritance();
      h.set( 6 );
      System.out.println( h.get() );
   }

   void set(
      int a ) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   int get() {
      System.out.println( a );
      return a;
   }
}
```

Now when I compiled it compiled and created Inheritance.class but the file name was In.java still when I compile as `public class Inheritance` it alerts me that the class should be changed as Inheritance.java . now when I run `java In`it shows an error as `Error: Could not find or load main class In` Now I again renamed the class as In as

```
class In {
   int a;

   public static void main(
      String args[] ) {
      Inheritance h = new Inheritance();
      h.set( 6 );
      System.out.println( h.get() );
   }

   void set(
      int a ) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   int get() {
      System.out.println( a );
      return a;
   }
}
```

Now when I compiled it compiled as In.class and when I run the output it had run the program showing

6
6

When I created the program with In.java and run the class with name as Class Inheritance it compiled and gave the Inheritance.class . 
1. If the class name and file name are different won't the compiler show up an error?
2. when I run the `java In` it shows `Error: Could not find or load main class In` as the In.class file is generated Why doesn't it detect it while compiling In.java with class name as Inheritance ? so can one class file use any other class file in the same directory?

Comment: Could you add some indentation to your code? This is very hard to read. You can use `ctrl + shift + f` in eclipse to automatically format it.

Comment: Sorry that I use a text editor for java @JeroenVannevel

Comment: you might want to consider to start with an actual IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. It will prevent a lot of mistakes and it makes developing a bazillion times more comfortable.

Comment: Ya but some books recommend me to start with text editor and command line to understand better.

Comment: Yes you're right. A console (nash or cmd.exe), vi (or notepad), and a compiler (gcc or javac) is the minimum you need. IDE is the next step.

Comment: Well its a compiler restriction it seems refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958456/why-cant-i-give-different-name-to-class-than-the-file-name . But I cant understand the pascal post @Aubin

Answer (score 5):

Any class which is declared `public` should be kept in a file of the same name. It is a compilation error if the names of the public class and the file which contains it are different. A class which isn't declared `public` can be kept in a file of a different name.

Note that the generated class files are named after the java classes, not the file names. Look at below examples.

In the below illustrations `X` is any valid name (except `Foo` and `Bar`).

Example 1:

```
// filename X.java (doesn't compile)
public class Foo {

}
public class Bar {

}
```

compiler complains about public classes `Foo` and `Bar` not being present in their own `.java` files.

Example 2:

```
// filename Foo.java (doesn't compile)
public class Foo {

}
public class Bar {

}
```

error same as above but applies only to `Bar` this time.

Example 3:

```
// filename Foo.java (compiles)
public class Foo {

}
class Bar {

}
```

generated files are `Foo.class` and `Bar.class`.

Example 4:

```
// filename X.java (compiles)
class Foo {

}
class Bar {

}
```

generated files are `Foo.class` and `Bar.class`.

Comment: Well if I dint add the public access specifier it compiles. Here the class name is Inheritance and file name is In.java . It compiles to give Inheritance.class

Comment: Ya . But it doesn't act according to the language specification then it shouldn't compile right?

Comment: Well its a compiler restriction it seems refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958456/why-cant-i-give-different-name-to-class-than-the-file-name . But I cant understand the pascal post @Nishant . If you know explain me too.

Comment: @xtreak Could you elaborate? I did't really understand your concern.

Comment: I couldn't explain the post by Pascal in the link that I posted in the comment. It seems relevant to the question.