# how java can compile file if file name and class name are different?

Tags: java

This file name is saved as `abc.java` but it can be compiled and generates `xyz.class`. Why is this possible?

```
class xyz {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("hello ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some documentation or something that makes you think that this isn't possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File name and class name different in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731853/file-name-and-class-name-different-in-java)

Comment: And I think this question doesn't deserve so many downvotes. I guess that's why you should post a formatted question, because if it would be in this form from the beginning, it could get some upvotes, too.

Answer (score 5):

Because only public classes need to be named the same as the .java file.
A class which isn't declared `public` can be kept in a file of a different name.

**Edit:** For a `public` class, `javac` would generate the following error:

```
abc.java:1: error: class xyz is public, should be declared in a file named xyz.java
public class xyz {
       ^
1 error
```

Comment: You didn't get any downvotes, actually. (Edit, apparently I'm just late.)

Comment: @Unihedron - there were at first; I was surprised as well

Comment: @Unihedron I did get a few, but apparently they backed off. It's not a perfect answer to not a perfect question... but it tells about the problem.

Comment: @EelLee You marked it as duplicate and answered it. Why ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I answered it first, then I thought it might be a duplicate question. BTW, is there anything wrong to answer in this case?

Comment: @EelLee Just curious :) Anyways I already up vote you.